# What is wrong with setting one list to another within function?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have built a function which carries out a set of operations given two parameters. The function looks as follows:

```
playingHand[Player_, Name_String] :=
 Row[{Style[Name <> ":", FontSize -> 48, FontFamily -> "Calibri"],
    Spacer[20]}~Join~
   If[Player == {}, {Style["Not playing", 48, Gray, 
      FontFamily -> "Calibri"]},
    {ButtonBar[Table[
       With[{i = i},
        Player[[i, 3]] :>
         {AppendTo[discardPile, Player[[i]]], 
          Player = Delete[Player, i]}],
       {i, Length@Player}]]}]]
```

The gist of this function is that as its first input it takes a list, which looks something like:

[image]

and displays the third elements of each list within that list:

[image]

It also makes these images clickable, so that when one of these cards is clicked, it should disappear from `player1` and get added to an initially empty list called `discardPile`. So far so good. When I run this function by itself without the defined function, namely like this:

```
ButtonBar[Table[
   With[{i = i},
    player1[[i, 3]] :>
     {AppendTo[discardPile, player1[[i]]], 
      player1 = Delete[player1, i]}],
   {i, Length@player1}]] // Dynamic
```

it works like a treat. The cards are clickable and they disappear from the `ButtonBar` as soon as they are clicked and added to `discardPile`. When I try to do the same from within the function though, namely `playingHand[player1, "Aron"] // Dynamic` it suddenly stops working. A `Set::shape` error message comes up warning that two lists are not the same length, and although it does add the card to `discardPile`, it does not remove it from `player1`. So:

1. What is wrong with this function and why won't it delete the card from the list when it is clicked, and
2. How come the same error does not occur when I run the function directly without calling it by its function name?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained example.

Comment: This question has an answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/3066)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a `Hold`-ish attribute on `playingHand` to preserve your first parameter as a symbol when it is replaced into the body of the function.

```
SetAttributes[playingHand, HoldFirst];
playingHand[Player_, Name_String] := ...
```

You have to do this because your function body is assigning to `Player`, and you can't assign to the explicit list that gets inserted for `Player` when your function is invoked. For example, something basically like this is happening there:

```
In[11]:= {1, 2, 3} = Delete[{1, 2, 3}, 2]

During evaluation of In[11]:= Set::shape: Lists {1,2,3} and {1,3} are not the same shape. >>

Out[11]= {1, 3}
```

Comment: you are a genius. I am eternally grateful to you!